# Converting decimals to commas in attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, delimiter

I'm using ArcMap v10.8.

I am currently making a map where I need to convert the decimal numbers in my attribute table to commas to fit the standard for a different country ie: changing 100.1 to 100,1 or 12.56 to 12,56. I can of course manually do this, but I have hundreds of attributes I need to change. I have tried selecting the field name > properties > Num [...], but it won't let me select the ellipses, likely because the attribute format is "string" instead of "float" or otherwise. when I made a new test field that was "float", I was able to click the ellipses and change the values by clicking "show thousands separators", but my issue is that the fields that I want to change, still won't change. Is there a way that I can convert the string fields to float, or another way (maybe using Python?) that I can easily convert all the values in my attribute table to commas instead of decimals? For reference, the attributes are then going to be displayed as labels to show pollution values of chemicals in a certain area.

[image]

Comment: Storing numbers as text is asking for trouble IMO. Would converting the field to a float type be a possibility? Perhaps storing ND as null? (What does it stand for anyway?)

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshot you clearly show values of "ND", this is text so the field has to remain text if you want to keep that text value.
If you open up the attribute table click on the options button in top left of table and you will see a find and replace.